# PHPMailer gives this page isn't working (HTTP ERROR 500)

Tags: php, phpmailer

I installed PHPMailer 6.01 and added the following lines to the PHP script,

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

The page loading in browser ends up with the error message:

> HTTP ERROR 500 This page is not working

Should I set any path somewhere?

Solved the problem by setting the full path autoload.php.

Comment: either check your error logs or enable `ini_set("display_errors","On");` to see the actual error.

Comment: It says Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/mydomain.com/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')

Comment: Is that the path where your plugin lives?

Comment: Not sure. I installed with the command "composer require phpmailer/phpmailer"

Comment: You gonna have to search for the folder and update your require path.

Comment: Solved the problem by setting the full path autoload.php.

Comment: Since `.` is in your `include_path`, it suggests that your script's cwd is not `/var/www/html/mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved such problem.

**Code**

```
//Load Composer's autoloader
require dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php';    
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

I hope this can help you too.

Comment: You can say `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`.